# Click anchor element using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, anchor

I know this has been covered elsewhere on this site, as well as many others, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I have an anchor tag that I use to show a lightbox form:

```
<a id="aNoData" href="#divNoData" class="fancybox">No Data</a>
```

I want to click it using a javascript function:

```
function fnNoData()
{
    //  This line works
    alert("this line works");   
    //  Neither of these lines work
    $('#aNoData').click();
     document.getElementById('aNoData').click();
}
```

I'm calling the function from my code behind, like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "fnNoData()", true);
```

When I do this, the first line (the alert box) shows fine. However, the other two lines (to click the anchor tag) do not. The non-working lines work great if I put them in my $(document).ready block (the anchor clicks on page load). So it seems that the lines to click my anchor work fine, just not in my function.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: _"work great if I put them in my $(document).ready block "_ if they work fine there, then where you are currently calling them is being called too soon, meaning the element does not exist yet, or the lightbox library hasn't had time to setup its own functionality for that element

Comment: Try adding your function in a script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: OK Patrick, thanks, and I did try putting the whole function inside my $(document).ready block, but it doesn't work at all there. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Thanks Difster, I tried that earlier. Same result.

Comment: Putting the whole function inside the ready block would make it scoped to that block, so wouldn't be able to be called outside of that block (you would see a _"fnNoData is not a function error"_ message in the console.)

Comment: @buckshot try with trigger i just give you example of it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took hours, but I finally brute-forced a solution.

As some repliers suggested, my code behind was trying to use the DOM before all elements were fully loaded. I got around that by changing the line in my code behind to this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "$(window).load(function() {fnNoData();});", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do click directly than you can use `trigger`

Check this hope this will helps you.

```
function fnNoData()
{
    //  This line works
    alert("this line works");   
    //trigger
    $('#aNoData').trigger('click');
    //document.getElementById('aNoData').click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nirav, that was one of the many, many things I tried. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

jquery click event is expecting a function
(not tested)

```
$('#aNoData').on("click", function() {
  console.log( "clicked the element with id aNoData );
});
```

in case you want to trigger the click(without the actual click), jquery has a function for that too:
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Thanks jpanzar. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from your comment

> *OK Patrick, thanks, and I did try putting the whole function inside my $(document).ready block, but it doesn't work at all there*

You should not define the whole function inside `$(document).ready()`, instead define it outside and call it from inside the `ready()` function

Your original function

```
function fnNoData(){
    //  This line works
    alert("this line works");   
    //  Neither of these lines work
    $('#aNoData').click(); 
}
```

Call it from `ready()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    fnNoData();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you James, and yes this will work, but I need to call my function from my code behind (see my original post). I was just putting stuff in my document.ready block to see if it works at all, which it does. The mystery, still unsolved, is why the code works there but not in my function.